# File transfer successful but won't exit while loop in C

Tags: c, linux, file, fwrite, transfer

EDIT: Changed the while loop condition from `> 0` to `!=0`. There are also 2 or more newlines being output on the terminal after printing the content, but in the file there aren't.

I'm doing a file transfer from the client to the server. The contents are transferred successfully, but when receiving it doesn't exit the while loop. Is my while condition somehow wrong? After I force stop the program, i can see that the file has actually been copied successfully, it just does not exit this while loop after writing everything to the file.

This is the code where I'm having trouble:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
int error;

while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) != 0){ 
                        
                        printf("writing: %s\n", buf);
                        if((error = fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp)) < 0)
                        {
                            printf("error");
                        }
                        if((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){
                            break;
                        }
                            
}
```

Tried to keep it as minimal as possible, as I'm sure there's something very simplistically wrong here.

EDIT: I tried it with a larger file, and it seems that its missing some content here and there but not in a consistent pattern.

EDIT: Here is the client side.

```
else if(strcmp(shortCommand, "put") == 0){
            
            char *tmp = buf + 4;
            char filename[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
            strcpy(filename, "filename ");
            strcat(filename, tmp);
            FILE *fp;
            printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
            fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
            if(fp == NULL){
                
                printf("ERROR: Requested file does not exist.\n");
                
            }
            else{
            printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((nw = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0){            //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }
            
            printf("Client sending file...\n");
            size_t bytes_read = 0;
            ssize_t bytes_written = 0;
            
            
            while((bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp)) != 0){ //sending the file contents
            
                if ((bytes_written = write(sd, buf, bytes_read)) < 0){
                    printf("Error sending client file.\n");
                }
            
            }
            
            fclose(fp);
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Is the transfer really successful? What are read by the 2ne `read` is discarded.

Comment: [read(2) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html): EOF is represented by return value `0`, so you should check for that.

Comment: I just tried it with a larger file, and after I force stop to exit that while loop, it appers only some of the content was transferred and not the whole document. Probably because my while loop didnt end correctly or maybe something else?

Comment: Ah, but `> 0` will be false when the return value is `0`...

Comment: `printf("writing: %s\n", buf);` is dangerous because the contents need not be null-terminated.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, thanks for that. So now ive made the while loop continue until its `!=0` like `while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) != 0)` but unfortunately there is no difference. The loop doesn't quit

Comment: @MikeCAT I was just using that to see on the terminal whether the content was actually read. But now that you mention it, after it outputs the file contents there are a couple new lines afterwards on the terminal, but in the file there aren't. How do I make sure that doesn't happen??

Comment: What does the sender do after sending contents? Does it close the stream?

Comment: `!= 0` will lead to an endless loop if `read()` returns an error. So the original version was better. Still you haven't explained the reason for the second `read()` inside the loop which is discarded.

Comment: What kind of stream are youe reading from?

Comment: @MikeCAT No, it simply closes the file that it was sending and that's it. Ill edit my question to show the senders part right now

Comment: if it's non-blocking `read()` might return 0 although the client hasn't finished sending but is just 'too slow'

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Oh...okay. Either way both seem to have no difference to it not stopping so maybe it's something else but i dont know. The reason I put that second read is because I was trying to force the loop to break when it finds the end of file/no bytes, but it didnt work

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I am using fread. I will post my client side that sends now, could you please look at that for me and see if it could be something wrong there?

Comment: well that 2nd `read()` anything else than what it returned if it was called from `while()`.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt im sorry i think you missed a couple words in the last comment. Or maybe im just dumb. Are you trying to say that the 2nd read is basically pointless?

Comment: The client doesn't seem to help much here. What dou you use to transfer data form client to server, in other words what is `sd`?

Comment: concerning 2nd `read()`: Yes all it does is that you discard parts of the data the client has sent. And I guess that's not what you want

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt `sd` is the name of the socket im using for the client and the server to communicate. And yes you're right about that. I'll remove it then. Is there anything I should be putting into the while loop however?

Comment: `while( read(...) > 0 )` should be OK. If you're experiencing that `read()` might return 0 although the client hasn't finished sending you can use `select()` to wait for data before actually calling `read()`

Comment: And it's important that the client really calls `close(sd)` after having finished. Otherwise the server can't recognize that the connection is terminated.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I was just playing around in my client sending part, and when I print out the number of bytes being sent after the sending is done, it actually sends 4 more bytes than the actual number of bytes in the file. I'm not sure why, but that while loop atleast exits..

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt The client does close the socket, when I type in quit. But thats in all my other code. Its weird because the client sends the file data, and it already re-prompts for me to input another command when the server hasn;t even finished it's while loop and responded to me

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt What I mean by that, is that in the server part I have a print statement after the while loop saying it's complete but it never reaches there. Only after I force stop, that print statement is output before the program exits

Answer (score 0):

The server code assumes that it will observe `read()` to return 0 after it reads all the data that the client transfers, but that will not happen just because the client stops sending data.  `read()` returns 0 to indicate that the end of the file has been reached, but "file" in that sense means the read side of its socket.  Until the client closes the peer socket, the server will not perceive EOF on its socket. And that's perfectly reasonable because until then, the client might send more data, proving that indeed EOF had not previously been reached.  Therefore, if the server tries to perform a (blocking) read on the socket after receiving all the data then it will block until the client sends more or closes the connection, or until it detects an error, is interrupted by a signal, *etc*..

If the client doesn't actually intend to send any further data after the file content then it should `close()` that socket after sending all the bytes of the file content, or at least [`shutdown()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) the write side.

If, on the other hand, the client is keeping the socket open because it intends to send more data later, then you need a new strategy.  In that case the end of the file content does not coincide with the logical end of the stream, and you therefore need a different mechanism to communicate to the server where the end of the file data is.  This is where communication protocols such as HTTP come in, but for your purpose, you don't need a protocol nearly as complicated as HTTP.

It might suffice, say, for the client to send data to the server as one or more chunks, each comprising a byte count followed by the specified number of bytes of content.  You could insist that the whole file content always go into one chunk, but if you want to allow splitting the file into multiple chunks then you could use a chunk length of zero to signal the end of the data.